# Какие элементы Вы используете у себя на сайтах?

Tags: интерфейс

Добрый вечер, как бы правильные сформулировать вопрос - поделитесь, пожалуйста, своим опытом, какие фичи для удобства навигации, UI Вы используете на своих сайтах? (Пример: постраничная навигация, "хлебные крошки" и так далее). Думаю, что вопрос будет очень полезен для начинающих веб-разработчиков. Заранее спасибо, надеюсь вопрос принесет пользу не только мне)

Comment: Отец, слышишь, рубит^W^W^W Дизайнер рисует, а я отвожу.

Не кодерское это дело, UI/UX заниматься, для этого специально обученные люди нужны, а кодер им только ограничивает полет фантазии техническими соображениями. А то у кодеров иногда рождаются дизайны достойные Франкенштейна.

Comment: Не могу не согласиться, но у многих программистов есть свои проекты - для души, куда, я например, не могу себе позволить нанять дизайнера и так далее.. И плюс нужно развиваться всесторонне... Так, что ИМХО тема будет полезна многих, особенно начинающим в этом нелегком деле)

Comment: Жаль, что никто не ответил по-существу... ;((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для сео оптимизации будет полезно:

- Хлебные крошки
- Похожие посты (если блог)

Для пользователя

- Конечно же меню(обычно вставляю в header и footer)
- удобный поиск
- Постраничная навигация
- И ещё для удержания пользователя всякие js приколы:)

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю что на современном сайте огромную роль играет умный быстрый поиск и обход ошибок (404 и т.д.) предложениями поиска похожих страниц (ато иногда одну букву пропустишь и если сайт не поможет так и не найдёшь нужную страницу) да и вообще без поиска и небыло бы современного интернета :)

Answer (score 2):

Готовые решения на jQuery - [здесь.](http://www.kendoui.com/web.aspx) Часто использую в своих проектах

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery UI - без комментариев](http://jqueryui.com/demos/)

[datatables - многофункциональный грид таблица](http://datatables.net/examples/)

[twitter bootstrap controls - современный дизайн в стиле твиттера](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons)

**UPD**
пока не забыл,есть [еще Metro UI элементы](http://aozora.github.com/bootmetro/index.html)